# ffmpeg was not found

Tags: python, discord, ffmpeg, discord.py

Помогите, уже третий час не могу решить проблему, облазил кучу форумов, нигде нет ответа на мою ошибку.
мой код:

```
import discord
import pyttsx3
import ffmpeg
from gtts import gTTS
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import AudioSource
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio


token = open('token.txt', 'r').read()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def сказать(ctx, *, content: str):
    print(content)
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    channel = await vc.connect()
    tts = gTTS( text= content, lang='ru' )
    tts.save('filename.mp3')
    await channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('filename.mp3', executable='C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'))
    channel.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(channel.source)
    channel.source.volume = 0.07


bot.run(token)
```

я даже указал путь к исполняему файлу ffmpeg.exe, добавил в path (перезапускал консоль) , скачивал другие билды ffmpeg, все без результатно.
Умоляю помогите, ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bots\преобразование\bot.py", line 21, in сказать
    await channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('filename.mp3', executable='C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 220, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 133, in __init__
    self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 142, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
discord.errors.ClientException: C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe was not found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe was not found.
```

Comment: Т.е. у вас по этому пути `C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe` файл есть?

Comment: @gil9red, да есть.

Comment: Попробовать в скрипте проверить, доступен ли файл *ffmpeg.exe* с помощью `os.path.isfile`. Если недоступен, значит как-то неправильно добавлено в PATH. Попробовать использовать двойные скобки '\\' в пути.